# Is there a way to display HTML in an XNA game on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to display a browser control over the top of an XNA game on Windows Phone 7?

Basically I need to display some HTML, and then allow the user to return to the game.

So it can be full-screen if need be. It could even involve switching to Internet Explorer, if there's a way to return to the game from IE?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was announced that XNA and Silverlight would be available together in the same app starting with Mango update.

That might allow you to get what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain It would be nice if we could pop an html screen like we do on the iPhone. I know if you embed an url you can open ie. but as far as I know you can only get back to your game via the hardware back button.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to directly display HTML content in your XNA application due to the differences in the UI core. You are able, however, to invoke the `WebBrowserTask`. All you need to do is add a reference to `Microsoft.Phone` and then add a `using` statement for `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks`.